# How to read this ES6 code utsing destructuring and initialization?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I ran into some code that looks like the following:

```
const {
  foo = []
} = this.options
```

Assuming in this case that `this.options` is an JavaScript `Object`, how does this work? Does all of `this.options` get assigned to `foo` and if `this.options` is `undefined`, does foo just get initialized to an empty array? I found this code confusing because `this.options` is not an `Array` but is instead an `Object` of key/val pairs.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? Kind of ridiculous.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to just try things out. What you'd observe is that a default value is assigned to foo in case it is missing within the to be assigned object

```js
function one() {
    const options = {};
    const {
        foo = []
    } = options;
    console.log(foo);
}

function two() {
    const options = {foo: 'bar'};
    const {
        foo = []
    } = options;
    console.log(foo);
}

function three() {
    const options = {};
    const {
        foo = 'foo',
        bar = 'bar',
        baz = 'baz'
    } = options;
    console.log(foo, bar, baz);
}

one();
two();
three();
```

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (emphesis mine ) :

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it **possible to unpack** values from arrays, or **properties from objects**, into distinct variables.

Not all of `this.options` get assigned to `foo`, it's unpacking `foo` from the Object :

```js
const options = {
  foo: ['foo', 'bar'],
  bar: 'hello world'
}

const {
  foo = []
} = options;

console.log(foo);
```

And `foo = []` is there to be a fallback to have an empty array if `this.options` does not have a property `foo` :

```js
const options = {
  bar: 'hello world'
}

const {
  foo = []
} = options;

console.log(foo);
```

If `this.options` is ` undefined, you'll get errors,

> options is not defined

```js
const {
  foo = []
} = options;

console.log(foo);
```

Or:

> Cannot destructure property `foo` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

```js
const options = undefined;

const {
  foo = []
} = options;

console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you [run it through babel](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBA3gKBjAZiEMC8MDaBdBAXyxigAsBLCAOhAAcoLwIBuIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.6.2&externalPlugins=) you'll see that if `this.options.foo` exists then it will be bound to the name 'foo' in that scope and if it doesn't then foo is set to an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an in-depths article for you to better understand ES6 Destructuring https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/

> Destructuring assignment allows you to assign the properties of an
>   array or object to variables using syntax that looks similar to array
>   or object literals. This syntax can be extremely terse, while still
>   exhibiting more clarity than the traditional property access.

For your sample script the assignment are looking for an object with property "foo" from right side. If it can not find it, it will assign foo with default value as empty array.

If the left side is null or undefined, the operator will throw an error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property`foo`of 'undefined' or 'null'."`

Answer (score 0):

```js
// A regular JS object.
this.options = {
    'a': 'a',
    'foo': 'bar',
    'z': 'z'
}
console.log('this.options.foo =', this.options.foo);
// this.options.foo === 'bar'

// Get 'foo' out of this.options. Becomes undefined if 'foo' doesn't exist in this.options.
const { foo } = this.options;
console.log('foo =', foo);
// foo === this.options.foo === 'bar';
const { nope } = this.options;
console.log('nope =', nope);
// typeof nope === 'undefined'

// Get 'zzz' if it exists, otherwise fall back to 1234.
const { zzz = 1234 } = this.options;
console.log('zzz =', zzz);
// zzz === 1234;
// zzz was set by its default fallback value.
```